# Angular Builder is not updating and I must change the builder

Tags: angular, configuration

I am new to Angular's configuration, and I do not know much about builders. I was following a tutorial on [how to use process.env in Angular](https://medium.com/@desinaoluseun/using-env-to-store-environment-variables-in-angular-20c15c7c0e6a) and it had to change some of the configurations in `angular.json`. I am getting an error when I do `ng serve` which is

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-builders/custom-webpack/dist/package.json'

I have 2 questions here. Please take a look at my angular.json, specifically the `projects.architect.serve`

```json
       "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack/dist:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "src/custom-webpack.config.ts"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/fitness-proj",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
```

```json
    "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "FitnessProj:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "FitnessProj:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

1. Whenever I change the "builder" key to any different value and I run `ng serve` or `ng update`, it gives me the error I quoted above. Is there perhaps something else I need to do to update the builder when I `ng serve`?
2. In the tutorial I provided above, the following led me to install an Angular builder that had this folder structure:

```
└── @angular-builders/
    └── custom-webpack/
        ├── dist/
        │   ├── browser/
        │   │   └── // a bunch of files
        │   └── dev-server/
        │       └── // a bunch of files
        ├── node_modules
        ├── builders.json
        └── package.json
```

I want to use custom webpack specifically the dev server. [1](https://medium.com/@desinaoluseun/using-env-to-store-environment-variables-in-angular-20c15c7c0e6a) is stopping me from doing so and also the fact that I do not know what I should put in "builder" and other parts of my code to use the specific builder in order for (the end goal) process.env to work.

If anyone can help me, that would be very great and I would I highly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the library match your angular version?

Comment: @OscarLudick what do you mean by that? Here are the `devDependencies` in my `package.json`  `"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",` and my Angular version 16.2.12

Comment: Can you try to update angular-builders to version 16, and then follow the guide. Here is the versions list: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack?activeTab=versions

Comment: @OscarLudick I just updated it to 16.0.0 and it's still looking for the `package.json` in the `dist` folder even though the `package.json` is in the same directory as the dist folder. (Basically giving me the same error lol)

Comment: Please update your question with the serve and build configuration using the angular-builders.

Comment: @OscarLudick do you mean the the JSON key-value pairs for `serve` and `build` in `angular.json`?

Comment: please change your builders to : `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",` and `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server"` for `build` and `serve`